# How to use Twig to split an HTML block in a template before an <h2>

Tags: symfony, twig

Given the following code in a variable:

```html
<section class="preparation">
                  
<h2>Los ingredientes</h2>
<ul>
<li>500 g de queso feta</li>
<li>½ cucharadita de pimienta negra</li>
<li>1 cucharadita de pimienta rosada</li>
<li>3 ramas pequeñas de romero</li>
<li>aceite de oliva </li>
</ul>

<h2>La preparación</h2>
<p>Corta el queso feta en dados y déjalos reposar sobre papel absorbente. Asegúrate de secarlos bien con el papel. Coloca cuidadosamente los dados de queso feta en el frasco con los granos de pimienta y el romero. Llena el frasco con el aceite de oliva hasta cubrir todos los ingredientes. Pon el frasco en la nevera durante por lo menos 12 horas antes de servir. Saca el frasco de la nevera para servir los cubos de feta a temperatura ambiente.</p>

</section>
```

How can I split the variable  before the `<h2>` and set additional divs around the new blocks?

The end result should render like this:

```html
<section class="preparation">

<div class="block">                 
  <h2>Los ingredientes</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>500 g de queso feta</li>
    <li>½ cucharadita de pimienta negra</li>
    <li>1 cucharadita de pimienta rosada</li>
    <li>3 ramas pequeñas de romero</li>
    <li>aceite de oliva </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="block"> 
  <h2>La preparación</h2>
  <p>Corta el queso feta en dados y déjalos reposar sobre papel absorbente. Asegúrate de secarlos bien con el papel. Coloca cuidadosamente los dados de queso feta en el frasco con los granos de pimienta y el romero. Llena el frasco con el aceite de oliva hasta cubrir todos los ingredientes. Pon el frasco en la nevera durante por lo menos 12 horas antes de servir. Saca el frasco de la nevera para servir los cubos de feta a temperatura ambiente.</p>
</div>
</section>
```

I did the following `TWIG` code but it eliminates the `h2` and does not finish the html block propperly.

```html
<section class="preparation">
    {% for contentblockitems in contentBlock|split('<h2>') %}
       <div class="block">
            {{ contentblockitems }}
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
</section>
```

Comment: Los ingredientes and preparacion are the only titles (under h2)? I mean you are not rendering more h2?

Comment: This one is very controlled, there are maximum 3 items. @martias solution worked perfectly setting up a conditional for some cases.

Comment: Look at a couple of examples: [This page has the code](http://kristinaencasa.com/cms/es/contenidos/dim-sum-de-camarones) , [and here is a rare case with 4 items](http://kristinaencasa.com/cms/es/contenidos/el-pavo-mas-facil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because when you split this:

```
<h2>Los ingredientes</h2>
<ul>
    <li>500 g de queso feta</li>
    <li>½ cucharadita de pimienta negra</li>
    <li>1 cucharadita de pimienta rosada</li>
    <li>3 ramas pequeñas de romero</li>
    <li>aceite de oliva </li>
</ul>

<h2>La preparación</h2>
<p>Corta el queso feta en dados y déjalos reposar sobre papel absorbente.</p>
```

using `<h2>` as the delimiter, you end up with this array:

```
{{ dump(contentBlock|split('<h2>')) }}

{# Prints this:

    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(0) ""
      [1]=>
      string(266) "Los ingredientes</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>500 g de queso feta</li>
            <li>½ cucharadita de pimienta negra</li>
            <li>1 cucharadita de pimienta rosada</li>
            <li>3 ramas pequeñas de romero</li>
            <li>aceite de oliva </li>
        </ul>

        "
      [2]=>
      string(103) "La preparación</h2>
        <p>Corta el queso feta en dados y déjalos reposar sobre papel absorbente.</p>"
    }

#}
```

As you can see, the first array item is an empty string, so the `for` loop produces one empty `<div class="block"></div>`. Furthermore, the rest of the array items are missing the starting `<h2>` tag (like you said), and you are not taking that into account in your `for` loop.

To avoid producing empty `div`s, you can skip array items that are empty strings by adding a condition ([see the documentation of `for` loops in Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition)):

```
{% for block in contentBlock|split('<h2>') if block|length %}
```

The `length` filter returns `0` for empty strings, and since `0` evaluates to `false`, empty array items are skipped.

It's even better to also use the `trim` filter to avoid producing `div`s with no content other than whitespace:

```
{% for block in contentBlock|split('<h2>') if block|trim|length %}
```

When you also add the missing starting `<h2>` tags, you end up with this code:

```
<section class="preparation">
    {% for block in contentBlock|split('<h2>') if block|trim|length %}
       <div class="block">
           <h2>{{ block }}
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
</section>
```

[See TwigFiddle.](https://twigfiddle.com/1d64es) Note that I had to use the `raw` filter to output unescaped HTML code. You probably don't need to do that in your code.

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much for this solution and the thorough explanation, I was going bonkers with this issue, @martias

Comment: @ganar Glad to help! You can mark this answer as the solution then.